# How to perform Boolean operation on thin surface using libigl?

Tags: graphics, computational-geometry, mesh, libigl

I am currently working on [libigl](https://github.com/libigl/libigl), and trying to grab the part of the a surface which locates inside another body. However, it seems than libigl only works with closed bodies:

Here is the code which works for closed bodies. `VA`,`VF` is a triangular prism and `VB`, `FB` is a tetrahedron:

```
#include <igl/readOFF.h>
//#define IGL_NO_CORK
//#undef IGL_STATIC_LIBRARY
#include <igl/copyleft/cgal/mesh_boolean.h>
#include <igl/viewer/Viewer.h>

#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <iostream>

Eigen::MatrixXd VA,VB,VC;
Eigen::VectorXi J,I;
Eigen::MatrixXi FA,FB,FC;
igl::MeshBooleanType boolean_type(
  igl::MESH_BOOLEAN_TYPE_UNION);

const char * MESH_BOOLEAN_TYPE_NAMES[] =
{
  "Union",
  "Intersect",
  "Minus",
  "XOR",
  "Resolve",
};

bool key_down(igl::viewer::Viewer &viewer, unsigned char key, int mods)
{
  switch(key)
  {
    default:
      return false;
    case 'A':
        viewer.data.clear();
        std::cout << "Loading A" << std::endl;
        viewer.data.set_mesh(VA, FA);
      break;
    case 'B':
        viewer.data.clear();
        std::cout << "Loading B" << std::endl;
        viewer.data.set_mesh(VB, FB);
      break;
    case 'C':
        viewer.data.clear();
        std::cout << "Loading C" << std::endl;
        viewer.data.set_mesh(VC, FC);
      return true;
  }  
  return true;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  using namespace Eigen;
  using namespace std;

  double prismSize = 150;
  double Heigh = 300;
  VA.resize(6, 3);
  VA << -prismSize, prismSize, 0,
      prismSize, prismSize, 0,
      0, 2 * prismSize, 0,
      -prismSize, prismSize, Heigh,
      prismSize, prismSize, Heigh,
      0, 2 * prismSize, Heigh;
  FA.resize(8, 3);
  FA << 1, 0, 2,
      5, 3, 4,
      4, 1, 2,
      2, 5, 4,
      3, 5, 2,
      2, 0, 3,
      0, 1, 4,
      4, 3, 0;

  double tetsize = 300;
  VB.resize(4, 3);
  VB << 0, 0, tetsize,
      -tetsize, 0, 0,
      tetsize, 0, 0,
      0, tetsize*2, 0;
  FB.resize(4, 3);
  FB << 2, 1, 3,
      2, 0, 1,
      3, 0, 2,
      1, 0, 3;


  igl::copyleft::cgal::mesh_boolean(VA, FA, VB, FB, igl::MESH_BOOLEAN_TYPE_INTERSECT, VC, FC);

  std::cout
      << "VA:" << std::endl << VA << std::endl << "==============" << std::endl
      << "FA:" << std::endl << FA << std::endl << "==============" << std::endl
      << "VB:" << std::endl << VB << std::endl << "==============" << std::endl
      << "FB:" << std::endl << FB << std::endl << "==============" << std::endl
      << "VC:" << std::endl << VC << std::endl << "==============" << std::endl
      << "FC:" << std::endl << FC << std::endl << "==============" << std::endl;

  // Plot the mesh with pseudocolors
  igl::viewer::Viewer viewer;

  viewer.data.set_mesh(VA, FA);
  //viewer.data.set_mesh(VB, FB);
  //viewer.data.set_mesh(VC, FC);  

  viewer.core.show_lines = true;
  viewer.callback_key_down = &key_down;
  viewer.core.camera_dnear = 3.9;
  cout<<
    "Press '.' to switch to next boolean operation type."<<endl<<
    "Press ',' to switch to previous boolean operation type."<<endl<<
    "Press ']' to push near cutting plane away from camera."<<endl<<
    "Press '[' to pull near cutting plane closer to camera."<<endl<<
    "Hint: investigate _inside_ the model to see orientation changes."<<endl;
  viewer.launch();
}
```

However, if I deleted one of the surfaces from `A` or `B`, like below for example:

```
//FA.resize(8, 3);
FA.resize(7, 3);
//FA << 1, 0, 2,
FA << 5, 3, 4,
      4, 1, 2,
      2, 5, 4,
      3, 5, 2,
      2, 0, 3,
      0, 1, 4,
      4, 3, 0;
```

The result mesh `C` will be empty (I want to get a open thin surface instead of a closed body). I think I am using the wrong function. Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be looking for `igl::copyleft::cgal::trim_with_solid`. This assumes you have an arbitrary mesh `A` and you have another closed mesh (actually a solid or [PWN](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/cg/mesh-arrangements/#definitions) mesh) `B`. The output will be a mesh of the same surface as `A` but with new edges added so that every face can be either flagged as inside `B` or outside/on `B`. Using the flags in the output list `D`, it's then trivial to extract the portion of `A` "trimmed" by `B`.

```
igl::copyleft::cgal::trim_with_solid(VA,FA,VB,FB,V,F,D,J);
```

Comment: So, what is `J` used for? It seems `J` frequently appears in APIs related to boolean, but I didn't find clear information about it.

Comment: `J` is going to tell you which face of the _input_ each face of the _output_ comes from. So suppose each face of your input had a different color, then `J` would tell you how to color your output mesh to match correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Boolean geometry requires that all surfaces are manifold without boundary. Any operations will result in an empty set otherwise. Here is a simple explination of manifolds:

[Manifolds](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/SLIDES/Mesh.pdf)

...and more reasoning on your question:

[Boolean Operations](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry)

Answer (score 1):

As described by @Eric Bischoff , Boolean geometry requires that all surfaces are manifold. However, I found a workaround for this, which at least fits with my requirement:

Assume that `A` is an arbitrary open surface and `B` is a closed manifold, and you want to cut off the outside part of surface `A`.

The workaround I want to describes, is to complete `A` to make it a manifold (`A'`) firstly. Then, subtract `A'` from B, and find the newly created facets, which exactly constitute the open thin surface you want.

Comment: Although I'm unaware of your data set and use case:

You could close up every contiguous boundary. If you have access to the halve edge data structure I believe you could just find ever neighboring edge that has exactly one neighboring face. This wouldn't work for all cases, but depending on your data it could work for most.

Comment: That's about as far as I'm able to take it as I've never used libigl. Good luck:)

Comment: @user5454506 Yes, my data structure is special, so I can use this route. Recently I am faced with a new geometry which can't be closed easily. I am gonna try `igl::copyleft::cgal::trim_with_solid(VA,FA,VB,FB,V,F,D,J);` suggested by @Alec Jacobson