# How to make a mesh manifold

Tags: graphics, computational-geometry, mesh, csg, libigl

I tried [`trim_with_solid`](https://github.com/libigl/libigl/blob/508cb9940f4d1e8e54137d5afe2fd2eb9c4dc672/include/igl/copyleft/cgal/trim_with_solid.h#L18) method to drill a hole into a 3D model:

```
igl::copyleft::cgal::trim_with_solid(m_VA, m_FA, m_VB, m_FB, m_V, m_F, m_D, m_J);
```

But for hollowed 3D models with inner and outer walls, the hole is *not* closed:

[image: Inner and outer walls]

#### Possible solution

As [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37986175/3405291), a possible solution might be to use [CSG operations](https://libigl.github.io/tutorial/#csg-tree) of:

```
igl::copyleft::cgal::mesh_boolean

// or

igl::copyleft::cgal::CSGTree
```

However, the CSG operations need the input meshes to be *manifold*.

#### Question

I couldn't figure out if libigl has any tool to make a mesh manifold. Is there such a tool? Is there any other library which might help?

Comment: There are `igl::is_vertex_manifold` and `igl::is_edge_manifold` methods which might be helpful ...

Comment: Do you consider other mesh libraries or igl only? Is it possible to download your input meshes?

Comment: @Fedor As far as I remember, a sample input mesh was this: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/93/Utah_teapot_%28solid%29.stl

Comment: @Fedor Eventually, I implemented the hole drilling feature by this Go package: https://github.com/reactivego/csg along with some tricks to make it fast.

Comment: Thanks, I see. Another option would be to use [MeshLib](https://meshinspector.github.io/MeshLib/html/group__BooleanGroup.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, I implemented the *hole drilling* feature by this Go package: https://github.com/reactivego/csg

Along with some tricks to make it fast:

## Workaround & tricks

It's assumed that the user usually creates holes for the flat/simple regions on the 3D model surface. So, these flat/simple regions are less likely to have faulty triangles. Accordingly, the following workaround might be proposed:

1. Consider the requested hole as a cylinder shape.

   1. This would be the *original* cylinder.
2. Scale up the hole cylinder by a percent. Like `20%`.

   1. This would be the *scaled* cylinder.
3. Extract any triangle of the 3D model which:

   1. ...is inside or intersecting with the *scaled* cylinder.
   2. 3D model would no longer contain those extracted triangles.
4. Convert the extracted triangles to CSG polygons.
5. Perform CGS operation between CSG polygons and the *original* cylinder.
6. Get the resulting polygons of CSG operation.
7. Convert the resulting polygons to new triangles.
8. Add new triangles to the 3D model.

## Conclusion

The above workaround was great. The *hole drilling* is fast and reliable.

[image: Screenshot]